# the difference b/w 1==n&1 and n&1==1 , n is an unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

this is a [program problem from leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-1-bits/).it gives an unsigned int n，ask you to return the numbers of bit '1';

```
int hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
int num=0;
for(;n!=0;n=n>>1)
{
    if(n&1==1)
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
}
```

this works perfectly,but

```
int hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
int num=0;
for(;n!=0;n=n>>1)
{
    if(1==n&1)
    {
        num++;
    }
}
return num;
}
```

this one cant work sometimes! i guess something is wrong when 1 calculate with an uint32_t,but i cant understand this clearly.

Comment: You don't need `==1` at all, replace with `if ( n&1 )`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight funnily enough that works for both interpretations of `n & (1 == 1)` and `(n & 1) == 1` :)

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might find [this method for counting ones](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Population%20Count%20%28Ones%20Count%29) interesting.

Comment: In addition to that, you can improve the **average** runtime performance of your own code, by changing `n=n>>1` to `n=n&(n-1)`.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb they are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`. Thus,

- `n&1==1` is `n & (1==1)`, while
- `1==n&1` is `(1==n) & 1`.

Comment: @barak manos thanks a lot, I can understand that `n=n&(n-1)` can remove a '1' every time, but why it is faster? It seems `n=n>>1` just need a SHR, but `n=n&(n-1)` needs more.