# Why does this if statement not run?

Tags: c, msp430

I have this C code, and neither the if or else block is running when I go through it with the debugger

Here is the code:

```
if(P2IN & BIT4 == BIT4 ){
    car_lock ^= BIT0;
    is_pressed = 1;
}else{
    is_pressed = 0;
}
```

At this point in the code, P2IN = `00010000`

It seems like neither the if or else block is running, what am I missing?

Comment: Clearly one of the two blocks must be running.  Try inserting an `abort()` (or your local equivalent) in each of them and see which one makes the program die.  If neither, then the program is not executing any of the code you posted.

Comment: `if(P2IN & BIT4 == BIT4 ){` --> `if((P2IN & BIT4) == BIT4 ){`

Comment: Is there any chance `is_pressed = 0` becomes a meaningless statement due to the code that follows? The compiler could be optmizing it away, but the debugger would still show the full code while you are stepping through it.

Comment: it can be stripped down to `if (P2IN & BIT4)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the difference b/w 1==n&1 and n&1==1 , n is an unsigned int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490996/the-difference-b-w-1-n1-and-n1-1-n-is-an-unsigned-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your `if` statement. The `==` operator takes higher precedence than the `&`, so what's really being evaluated is:

```
(P2IN & (BIT4 == BIT4))
```

You need to change your code to:

```
if ((P2IN & BIT4) == BIT4)
```

There's a useful webpage about operator precedence [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).